# Enviar datos de consulta por medio de formulario POST!

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Debo enviar los datos que están en una consulta, pero los he puesto en un formulario para dar más comodidad al usuario al momento de visualizarlos y dar clic en enviar. El error que me aparece con respecto a cada variable es que "Las variables no están definidas".

```
Notice: Undefined index: identificador in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\relacion_jugadores.php on line 4
```

**Formulario**

```
    
    <input type="text" name="identificador" value="<?PHP echo $dato["identificador"];?>" hidden="true">
    <input type="text" name="usuario"  value="<?PHP echo $dato["usuario"];?>" hidden="true">
  
        <span class="input-group-text">Nombres</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="nombres" class="form-control" value="<?PHP echo $result["nombre"];?>">
    </div>
      <span class="input-group-text">Apellidos</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" value="<?PHP echo $result["apellidos"];?>">
    </div>
  
      <span class="input-group-text">Correo Eléctronico</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="correo" class="form-control" value="<?PHP echo $result["correo_electronico"];?>">
    </div>
    
     <span class="input-group-text">Teléfono</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control" value="<?PHP echo $result["telefono"];?>">
    </div>
  
     <span class="input-group-text">Dirección</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control" value="<?PHP echo $result["direccion"];?>">
    </div>
     <span class="input-group-text">Gustos</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="gustos" class="form-control" value="<?PHP echo $result["gustos"];?>">
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Enviar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Luego de enviar este formulario que contiene los registros provenientes de una consulta, los pasa a este archivo por metodo POST. Código php que inserta los datos.

```
include 'conexion.php';

$iden = $_POST['identificador'];
$user = $_POST['usuario'];
$nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$tel = $_POST['telefono'];
$dir = $_POST['direccion'];
$mensaje = $_POST['gustos'];


$registrar = mysqli_query($conexion,'INSERT INTO relacion_jugadores (identificador,usuario,nombre,apellidos,correo,telefono,direccion,gustos) VALUES ("'.$iden.'","'.$user.'","'.$nombres.'","'.$apellidos.'","'.$correo.'","'.$tel.'","'.$dir.'","'.$mensaje.'")') or die('<p>¡Error al Registrar!</p><br>'.mysql_error($conexion));

?>
```

Comment: Podrias colocar el codigo completo de tu archivo relacion_jugadores.php?

Comment: Ese es todo el código, solo necesito que inserte los datos.

Comment: No veo donde estas abriendo las etiquetas de tu forma, podrías poderlo por favor?

Comment: Es un formulario que tiene el código arriba, este tiene un form acction hacia "relación_jugadores.php", que tiene el php para insertar los datos.

Comment: Lo que veo es que el primer codigo que insertaste donde esta el formulario, en ningun momento se abre la etiqueta form

Comment: Tienes razón no la agregue aqui al post pero si está en el código, es este: <form class="form-inline" action="relacion_jugadores.php" method="POST">

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema está al hacer que html muestre un código php, para esto no puedes mezclar comillas dobles para todo si en tu `echo` va una variable en php, en dicho caso debes usar comillas simples para el `echo` para que el intérprete de php muestre correctamente las variables.

```
value="<? echo $dato['identificador'];?>"
```

También para evitar problemas de identificación de variables podrías agregar el campo `id=""` igual al campo `name=""`, ya que hay ocasiones en que dependiendo del tipo de input podrá tomar uno u otro valor; ejemplo cuando usas radio button, te dejo un link que podrá orientarte.

Además estás usando `mysql_error($conexion));`. Te faltó `mysqli_error(...)`, estas mezclando una librería que esta en desuso.

[enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas:

1. De inyección de SQL: Nunca debes confiar en lo que viene del cliente (hay que sanitizar los string y los enteros fijate en la documentación sobre las funciones `filter_var` y `filter_input`).
2. Estás usando dos variables diferentes, `$dato` y `$result`, está claro que `$dato` o no es un array o no tiene la clave `identificador`definida.

Si agregas el archivo completo será más fácil decirte exactamente qué hacer y por qué.

Comment: Lo que hay arriba del form es esta consulta: <?php
 session_start();

  include 'conexion.php';
   
  if (isset($_SESSION)){
    $user = $_SESSION['name'];
    $update = "UPDATE nombre_tabla SET oportunidad = 1 WHERE columna_usuario = '$user'";
  mysqli_query($conexion,$update);

}

else{
 header('location:./');
}

?>

Comment: Despues biene esta: if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){

  $user = $_SESSION['name'];
  $consulta = "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$user' AND identificador=identificador";
  $ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

  foreach ($ejecucion as $dato):
  ?>
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $dato['columna_usuario']?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="identificador" value="<?php echo $dato['identificador']?>"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
  endforeach;
?>

Comment: $result viene de una consulta y $dato proviene de otra.